# What is the inverse of $\sqrt{ax+bx^4}$?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

I am interested in the inverse function of:

$$
y=\sqrt{ax+bx^4}
$$

Where $a,b,x \in [0,1]$.Furthermore, $a+b=1$ but I’m not so sure that’s as relevant. This came up in the course of (physics) research, and I have to admit it is not immediately clear how to proceed. Wolfram Alpha gives a closed form but it is extremely convoluted and I don’t trust that that form is as simple as it could be. What is the general approach for finding an inverse like this, and does this one have a ‘neat’ form?

Comment: General way: If $y=f^{-1}(x)$ then $f(y) = f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ solve for $y$.  So in this case $x=\sqrt{ay + by^4}$.  $x^2 = ay+by^4$ and solving that is hard as hell.  No reason to assume it'd be easy.

Answer (score 1):

The general procedure is: solve for $x$ as a function of $y$. There's a problem, though, which is that it's hard to solve equations sometimes. This one isn't so bad, because first you can square both sides to get $y^2 = ax + b x^4$, and then you can apply the [general formula for roots of quartic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). The complexity of that formula probably accounts for the "extremely convoluted" solution you got from Wolfram Alpha; good luck on finding a simpler formula.

Just be happy that the expression under the radical wasn't a general quintic polynomial $a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + ex^4 + dx^5$: a famous theorem which one learns in a course on Galois Theory says that there is *no general formula* whatsoever, expressed solely in terms of arithmetic and radicals, for solutions to quintic equations.

The moral of the story is: there is no "general approach for finding an inverse like this", in the sense that there is no general approach which solves all equations. Every equation to solve can present one with a new mathematical adventure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose in retrospect it is obvious that the best approach would be to using the roots of quartic equations, I feel a little silly for having asked. The form of the equation in question seemed ‘simple’ enough where I was put off by the ‘complicated’ expressions I was finding.

Answer (score 1):

If this comes from a problem in physics, I suppose that approximations could be sufficient.

Expanding as Taylor series around $x=0$ gives
$$\sqrt{ax+bx^4}=\sqrt{ax} +\frac{b x^{7/2}}{2 \sqrt{a}}-\frac{b^2 x^{13/2}}{8
   a^{3/2}}+\frac{b^3 x^{19/2}}{16 a^{5/2}}+O\left(x^{25/2}\right)$$ Now, using series reversion
$$x=\frac{y^2}{a}-\frac{b y^8}{a^5}+\frac{4 b^2 y^{14}}{a^9}-\frac{22 b^3
   y^{20}}{a^{13}}+O\left(y^{26}\right)$$

Another possible solution could be using Padé approximants. This would give for example, as another  *approximation*,
$$\frac{6 \sqrt{a}  \left(a^4-b y^6\right)}{6 a^4+5 b y^6}\sqrt{x}+\frac{ y^5
   \left(56 a^4 b-b^2 y^6\right)}{4 a^3 \left(6 a^4+5 b y^6\right)}x-y=0$$ which is a quadratic in $\sqrt{x}$.